# Architecture to check for user properties in bulk?

Tags: mysql, architectural-patterns, enterprise-architecture

We run an infrastructure in our organization, where a list of configs are provided and we check which config a given user satisfies.
For eg:

```
config_1 = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}
config_2 = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 4}
config_3 = {"a": 3, "b": 2, "c": 3}
```

For each attribute there is a sql query to get the data, for eg:

```
Select a from table_a where user_id = 1;
Select b from table_b where user_id = 1;
Select c from table_c where user_id = 1;
```

Now lets say user_id 1 has following data

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 4
```

Then we know that `user_id 1` satisfies `config_2`.

In our current setup, there are a fixed set of 100 attributes, and at a given amount of time engineers can use upto 100 configs to check which one of them a user satisfies.

What are the example of some scalable architectures to solve this problem ?

1. I cannot cache SQL queries because some attributes data changes very frequently.
2. I can use publish subscribe pattern to create one dict which has data for all user attributes and probably save them in memory. Doing that for a large user base looks like lot of compute time has to be spend as not all users would be active, we can implement this architecture of only active users.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Can you cache all 100 configs x 100 attributes in memory, use some kind of pub-sub to update that cache when the data changes and then do a quick lookup for every user hitting the system?

Comment: Yes we can, was wondering if there is any other architectural pattern to solve this problem ?

Comment: What's the matter with caching those 10k values in memory? A solution that works is a good solution.

Comment: So total no of users on the platform are 10 million, and out of them only hundred thousand are daily active users, so we also need another system which adds this data only for daily active user instead of all and handles expiry accordingly.

Ofcourse this can be done, was wondering if there is any other solution to same problem.

Comment: Are the properties, e.g. `a`, `b`,... always simple values, such as represented in your case as numbers?

Comment: What is the chance that a user does not match any of the configs? What should happen then? Do the provided configs have additional properties other than the data that can be retrieved from the database? If not, why go through the hassle of matching a user to a config rather than creating a config instance from the properties you obtain from the database for that user?

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau You have a good suggestion, thats one optimisation i am currently working on, can you post answer with this suggestion i will accept it.